# How to define trait bounds for associated type?

Tags: rust

How can I rewrite the below code in elegant way ?

```rust
pub trait Block {
    type I: Block;
    type T: Iterator<Item = Self::I>;

    fn child() -> Self::T;
}
```

Can I remove the associated type `I` and use only one i.e, `T` ?

Expecting something like this:

```rust
pub trait Block {
    type T: Iterator<Item: Block>;

    fn child() -> Self::T;
}
```

Comment: You could make the trait or, since 1.65.0, the associated type `T` generic over a type that implements `Block` but that would change the semantics of the  trait. To achieve exactly the behavior you have right now, I'm not aware of another way than your first. What's so wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make restrictions for each method:

```rust
pub trait Block 
{
    type T: Iterator;

    fn child() -> Self::T where <<Self as Block>::T as Iterator>::Item: Block;
}
```

But it seems to be useless. I don't see any way of creating such a type, that can satisfy trait bounds like this, as long as these bounds are recursive.

Comment: Such a type isn't hard to create. `T::Item = Self` would trivially satisfy the trait bound.

Comment: You can add the constraint to the associated type: `type T: Iterator where <Self::T as Iterator>::Item: Block;` but for some reason I don't understand you have to repeat it for every function that mentions `T`.

Comment: @rodrigo no, you can't. Just try it.

Comment: Well, I can _write_ the trait, [(payground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=106a53612a9d5e8881a5342f3a83de1b) but when trying to implement it for any type it fails saying:  compiler crashes with "overflow evaluating the requirement `<() as Block>::T == _`", which I find quite weird.

Comment: That's why you need trait bound on method, not on associated type: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=782a27593a3a907d504eea550bd1a33f